# Number of pairs corresponding to divisibility

Tags: combinatorics

How many pairs of $(x, y)$ are there where $x, y$ are natural numbers and none of $x, y$ is greater than $210$ such that $3$ divides $x^3+y^3$? $(x, y)$ and$(y, x)$ are counted as the same pair.

Here is my approach: $3$ divides $x^3+y^3$ so $3$ divides $x+y$. Since $x+y \le 210+210=420$, $x+y$ can take on values from $3$ to $420$. Now number of natural solutions to the equation $x+y=n$ where $(x,y),(y,x)$ are counted once is floor function of $\frac{n}{2}=[\frac{n}{2}]$. So the total number of pairs should be $[\frac{3}{2}]+[\frac{6}{2}]+\cdots+[\frac{420}{2}]=1+3+4+6+\cdots+210$ which can be easily calculated using formula of arithmetic progressions.

But i am not sure of this solution since we did not take into account the case when $3$ divides $x^2-xy+y^2$. I again will be very happy if someone points out my mistake.

Also is there any easy solution using slick combinatorial arguments?

Comment: Note that either we have that $3$ divides both $x$ and $y$ or we have that one of them is $1\pmod 3$ and the other is $-1\pmod 3$.

Comment: In fact, if 3 divides $x^3+y^3$ then 3 divides $x+y$ AND 3 divides $x^2-xy+y^2$ (so 9 divides $x^3+y^3$).

Comment: @ascheplar i don't think so,if $3$ were to divide both of them,$x$ and $y$ both must also be divisble by $3$

Comment: @lulu could you post the complete solution please?

Comment: You can do it yourself:  Take the case in which both $x,y$ are divisible by $3$.  How many multiples of $3$ are there?  Well, we go from $3\times 1$ to $3\times 70$, so $70$.  We want to choose $2$ from that, so $\binom {70}2$.  Other case is similar.

Comment: Could you please show the other case as well? The answer is actually $70C2+70^2+70$,so there seems to be $3$ cases.

Comment: Oh, that's right.  I forgot that in choosing two multiples of $3$ we have to include the case in which $x=y$.  That is an additional $70$.  My argument only counted those in which $x\neq y$.  Thus there are $\binom {70}2+70$ cases in which $3$ divides both $x,y$.

Comment: To be complete;  note that there are $70$ each of the cases in which one of them is $3n+1$ and the other one is $3n+2$, hence $70^2$ ways to choose one from each.